# Function is not loading correctly

Tags: r

I have the following function:

```
histogram <- function()

eucaris_countries <- c("NL", "B")
counter_eucaris = 0
counter_niet_eucaris = 0

ikr_set <- read.csv2("IKR data.csv", header = T)

for (i in 1:nrow(ikr_set)){
if (ikr_set$LAND_HERK %in% eucaris_countries) {
    counter_eucaris + 1 
}
else {
    counter_niet_eucaris +1
}
counter_eucaris
}
```

It should do the following:

1. Read in a .csv file
2. Loop through each row and check whether the column name of the row $LAND_HERK equals one the items in vector "eucaris_countries"
3. Add up 1 to the variable counter_eucaris / counter_not_eucaris (depending on whether the column name contains a name in the vector.

When I try to load the script I get an error however:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'eucaris_countries' not found
```

I do not get what is going wrong here... Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you put an open bracket at the top after `function() {` and at the bottom at the end of the function?

Comment: @JohnPaul, thanks that helped me further! However when I execute the function now I get: 1: In if (ikr_set$LAND_HERK %in% eucaris_countries) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. Any thoughts what goes wrong here?

Comment: You are comparing all the values in `ikr_set$Land_HERK` with `eucaris_countries` so there are whole of values. I think you want `irk_set$Land_HERK[i]` if you really want to loop through.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a function to do what you want to do here?  It looks like you're trying to count the number of rows where a variable is in (and not in) a vector elements.  You could do that with code like this ...

```
# example fake data
ikr_set <- data.frame(LAND_HERK=c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "NL"))
# elements of interest
eucaris_countries <- c("NL", "B")

sum(ikr_set$LAND_HERK %in% eucaris_countries)
sum(!(ikr_set$LAND_HERK %in% eucaris_countries))
```